# I have 2005 golf 1 1.6 feul injections.car starts fine then rough idle high and low on the Rev counter then cutts off

Tags: maintenance

I had diagnosis Don and the results were.
Manifold press send signal too high.
Throttle valve adapter/potentiometer open circuit short circuit to B+
Throttle valve potentiometer open circuit short circuit to B+
These codes were not cleared.i replaced the coil and leads then replaced petrol relay and temp sensor as well as the maf sensor.problem is still there and getting worst.
Can anyone help please

Comment: Why didn't you address the codes?  I'd be checking my throttle body.

Comment: The guy that did the diagnosis left me hanging and said his busy I must wait till he has time.i checked the throttle body cleaned and sprayed with the spray but nothing

Comment: It sounds to me that there is an issue with the throttle body position sensor (i.e. the potentiometer).  If that's a separate part on this model, you may want to check and replace it.

Comment: Hi guys.thanks for the response and help.i changed the throttle body position sensor but still having an idle problem.can these error be codes be causing my stress. 00518 00530  00519

Comment: I also have a code 00543 maximum speed exceeded.can anyone help